# attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

Tags: python

when tried to execute this code, it is showing 'attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence' error.
code:
import re
import numpy as np

code:

```
import re
import numpy as np

output_directory = './fine_tuned_model'

lst = os.listdir(model_dir)
lst = [l for l in lst if 'model.ckpt-' in l and '.meta' in l]
steps=np.array([int(re.findall('\d+', l)[0]) for l in lst])
last_model = lst[steps.argmax()].replace('.meta', '')

last_model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, last_model)
print(last_model_path)
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type=image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_fname} \
    --output_directory={output_directory} \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix={last_model_path}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not share code or traceback as images. This is inaccessible to people who use screen readers, and also makes debugging harder.

Answer (score 1):

Think the error is saying exactly what is happening. You are creating `steps` with no data so argmax() won't run. Perhaps you need to adjust how it's loaded so data is in steps. Hard to say based on info provided

### Simplified Example to Demonstrate Issue:

```
steps = np.array([1,2,3])

#Works fine with data
print(steps.argmax())

#argmax() throws an error since the array is empty
emptySteps = np.delete(steps,[0,1,2])
print(emptySteps.argmax())
```

### Possible Workaround

Appears you are searching a directory. If there are no files available, you may not want an error. Could achieve this with a simple check before running to see if there are files to process

```
if steps.size > 0:
    print("Do something with argmax()")
else: 
    print ("No data in steps array")
```

Comment: please check the project in "https://github.com/shivam1423/Pest-detection".